# Wtat's differences between getRegion and showChildView

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, marionette

```
const template1 = _.template('<h1>Marionette says hello!</h1>');
const template2 = _.template('<h1>Marionette is awesome!</h1>');
const myView1 = new Mn.View({template: template1});
const myView2 = new Mn.View({template: template2});
const MyView = Mn.View.extend({
  el: '#container',
  template: false,
  regions: {
    region1: '#region1',
    region2: '#region2'
  },
  onRender() {

    this.getRegion('region1').show(myView1);
    this.showChildView('region2', myView2); 

  }
});
const myView = new MyView();
myView.render();
```

What's differences between 2 methods in this code `getRegion` and `showChildView`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's only a shortcut syntax, from the [Marionette doc](http://marionettejs.com/docs/v2.4.2/marionette.layoutview.html#basic-usage):

> ```
> layoutView.getRegion('menu').show(new MenuView());
>
> layoutView.getRegion('content').show(new MainContentView());
> ```
>
> There are also helpful shortcuts for more concise syntax.
>
> ```
> layoutView.showChildView('menu', new MenuView());
>
> layoutView.showChildView('content', new MainContentView());
> ```

The [code behind `showChildView`](https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.marionette/blob/c72e95ae58c7de3572eb04c49859a59c082684fe/src/mixins/regions.js#L134)

> ```
> showChildView(name, view, ...args) {
>     const region = this.getRegion(name);
>     return region.show(view, ...args);
> }
> ```

Comment: @zloctb It's not complicating things, it's making them easier to type and read.